# Override ctrl+h in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I would like to make a chrome extension for browser history, and when the users presses ctrl+h, I would like it to open my extension rather than opening the browser's normal history.

Here is the code I've attempted, but it still only opens the browser's normal history.

```
document.onkeydown = function (e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey && (e.key == 'h' || e.key == 'H')) {
        e.preventDefault();
        chrome.browserAction.openPopup();
    }
}
```

Comment: The document has no control over the browser. Capturing events in the document (your `document.onkeydown`) isn't going to change how the browser behaves.

Comment: @Ouroborus I've used lots of web sites that override Ctl-f for their own search function. Is Ctl-h different?

Comment: Ctrl-f is "Find in page" so it makes sense you could override that from the page. Ctrl-h brings up the browsing history (which isn't tied to a specific tab) so that would be beyond the control of any specific page. There are permission settings to change that behavior (somewhere). For an extension, [you should use the extension's manifest and service worker](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/commands/).

Comment: There's no chrome.browserAction.openPopup in ManifestV2 in stable Chrome. There will be chrome.action.openPopup in ManifestV3, but your approach won't work when the user focuses the address bar, so a better approach is to set _execute_browser_action or _execute_action (ManifestV3) key in [commands](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands).